# Google Scripts Error "You do not have permission to call toast"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

My coworkers started complaining today about problems they were having on a scheduling sheet that I automate with Google Scripts.  I have not touched the code for this Spreadsheet for some time and was surprised to see the Stackdriver Logs full of errors:

> You do not have permission to call toast at createJobFolder(Job_Files:112) at evaluateJobCode(Job_Code:29) at check(Triggers:14)

Did Google change anything about the permissions for `.toast()`? There was no new permission requests and I could not trigger one.  Please advise.

Here is a quick way I have found to reproduce the error:

1. Paste the following code into the Script Editor:

```js
function myFunction() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('hello')  
}
```

2. Run it to ok the permissions
3. Assign an edit event to it
4. Share it with another account and make an edit to reproduce the error.

Comment: Post some relevant code to help with diagnosing the error.

Comment: here is an example: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('5013 updated.');

Comment: Again this code has been running very actively for months without triggering this error.  I have not touched it in weeks and suddenly all of the toast calls in the code were triggering this error starting this morning around 9:00 AM PST

Comment: is the code being run from a trigger, or manually by individual users?

Comment: It is being run from an edit trigger. The effective user is myself

Comment: If you really want help you’re gonna have to show us a little bit more of your code

Comment: I am continuing to have this error so I have reported it to the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68857051